# Нужно соединить два MySQL запроса в один, помогите пожалуйста!

Tags: select, mysql

Нужно соединить два MySQL запроса в один, помогите пожалуйста!

```
SELECT id, product_id, customer, quantity, ip, time FROM basket WHERE customer='".session_id()."'
```

и второй SQL запрос

```
`SELECT id, title, price, images, category FROM products WHERE id='$parent_id'`
```

(переменная из первого запроса).

Comment: Что значит фраза "переменная из первого запроса"?  Какая именно переменная из 6?

Comment: да, $parent_id = $row['parent_id'];

Вот, что выдал MySQL - Unknown column '0677a39169639f4b2daeefb7d6bd8619' in 'where clause' ;-((

Comment: Дык надо ж подумать про то, что я пример написал.. Реально запрос так выглядеть будет:

    mysql_query("select p.id as p_id, p.title, p.price, p.images, p.category, b.id as b_id, b.customer, b.quantity, b.ip, b.time from basket b left join products p ON p.id = b.product_id where b.customer = '".session_id()."'");
Как и у тебя было написано
Или mysql_query(sprintf("select p.id as p_id, p.title, p.price, p.images, p.category, b.id as b_id, b.customer, b.quantity, b.ip, b.time from basket b left join products p ON p.id = b.product_id where b.customer = '%s'", session_id()));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы бы поставили задачу в русле чего вы хотите добиться словесно, например: "Получить товары для данного пользователя + похожие товары", с разъяснением критерия похожести товара.

Чисто технически на ваш вопрос можно ответить: используйте LEFT JOIN - соедините себе два запроса в один.